# upgrade typo3 from 4.1.7 to 6.1 step by step

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am new at typo3 .I need to update from 4.1.7 to the latest.
which steps should I follow please suggest me ..
and which type of error possibly occur
i have **php 5.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some simple ways to find out the errors/issues after upgrading typo3!**

1. Check the symlinks.
   Usually we point the typo3, t3lib, index.php to the folders/files inside typo3_src folder which is symlinked to the typo3 source package (typo3_src_4.5 etc). Sometimes even after symlinking the source folder, symlinks may point to the older version. In this case we need to symlink the typo3, t3lib &index.php to the folders/files inside the typo3 source folder after symlinking the typo3 source (typo3_src) folder to the new typo3 source.
2. Use upgrade wizard.
   If you’re not sure whether the upgrade is complete or not then check the “Install tool > Upgrade Wizard” for current typo3 version and do the steps mentioned in it.
3. Set Display errors to 2.
   Getting a blank backend or front end is very common after upgrade. This might be due to some php errors, compatibility issues etc. An easy way to find the error is to set
   “Install tool> All Configuration > displayerrors” to 2 and add our IP address to
   “Install tool> All Configuration > devIPmask” so that the errors will be visible only for our IP.
4. Clear typo3temp.
   Empty the typo3temp folder. Otherwise rename the existing one and create a new one.
5. Delete the cached files.
   Remove the typo3_cached files in “typo3conf” folder.
6. Find out extension conflicts.
   If none of the above methods allow you to work with the new typo3 version, then there’s a chance for extension conflict. A simple way is to rename the “typo3conf/ext” folder (to something like “typo3conf/ext_renamed”) and create a new empty “typo3conf/ext” folder. Check the backend. If it works fine, then it’s clear that there’s an extension conflict. Bring back the “typo3conf/ext” folder and test the extensions inside it (here also the renaming method can be used – rename the extensions one by one and check whether the backend is ready or not).
7. Check the error log.
   Go through the error log and findout what’s missing or what’s problem with our new installation. Make sure that source file/folder permissions are correct.
8. Debug “typo3conf/localconf.php” file.
   Comment all the details in localconf.php file except the data needed for database connection. If backend is available after doing so, the comment it sectionwise and continue debugging. Make sure that required extensions mentioned in localconf.php are available.
   (like : $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['requiredExt'] = ‘cms,lang,sv,restrictlogin’; )
   We can also find out the errors by adding
   ini_set(‘display_errors’,'On’);
   at the end of localconf file.

   **Note:** While upgrading to typo3 4.6 make sure that you’re using Php 5.3 and the SOAP module is enabled. Before you upgrade always have a look at the typo3 version requirements in typo3 wiki.

**Other notes**

- **Shortcut links not working after typo3 upgrade for multilingual
  sites.**

  In multilanguage websites after typo3 upgrade the shortcuts works fine for default language pages but not in other languages. The reason is – for alternative language the pages will be in “Standard” mode which worked old typo3 versions but not in latest typo3 versions. So just changing “Standard” mode to “Shortcut” mode for alternative page languages will solve the issue.
- **New extension manager.**

  The new extension manager may appear a little bit confusing but it’s very simple and efficent. Even though our eyes may not find the options that we’d used earlier very easily, they still exist.
  eg: How to get the old version of a typo3 extension?
- **Merging css files and java-script as a built in feature.**

  From typo3 4.6 onwards we can merge and minify the css and js files that are used in our website by using the new typo3 features like:
  config.concatenateJsAndCss = 1
  config.concatenateJs = 1
  config.concatenateCss = 1
- **Check status report.**

  typo3 status report notice
  Check the typo3 status report to get an overview of the site’s parameters as well as any problems detected with the installation.

Reference link: **[How to upgrade typo3?](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/how-to-upgrade-typo3-version/)**

Comment: Nice link sankar can you plz suggest me how much  time require for upgrading process??thanks..

Comment: Depends on the extensions are you've installed.

Comment: There may be compatibility issues. After upgrading to each typo3 version update your extensions also.

Comment: Hi Sankar, I want to upgrade typo 3.6.2 version to latest version(9.5), what will be the best solution? Upgrading or rebuild it from scratch? Is upgradation possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's huge list of changes between 4.2 > 4.5 > 6+ from my long practice I can say it will be probably easier to build brand new page using 6.x and new extensions created for it instead of  upgrading and keeping old extensions (most probably some of them are not maintained anymore).

BTW, as you can see in [the download section](http://typo3.org/download/) for TYPO3 6.0+ you need at least PHP ver. 5.3.7

Edit:

you should update TYPO3 version by version that means 4.2 > 4.3 > 4.4 ... When you'll go to the 4.6 refresh the list of available extensions in ExtensionManager and the update one by one, always check changelog of extension to make sure that newest version isn't dedicated for TYPO ver. 6.x (or 4.7) in such case you will need to find some other version.

Of course you need to make a copy of the whole service (files and database) so in case of problems you will be revert to previous state... and don't do it on working server, as probably it will contain some problems to resolve during this migration.

[Here's full description by TYPO3 wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/Upgrade)

Comment: as i have php 5.3 i may not able to go with  6.1.x,will go with 4.6 Can you show me the way how to upgrade the extensions?